# JavaScript: Convert different Values in a single Number

Tags: javascript

I have following three values:

- Week (number between 1 and 52)
- Year (number between 0 and 99)
- String (between "aa" and "zz")

Is there any way to convert ("pack") this to a number between 0 and 999999? Or is this is too much information for a number of 6 digits?

The goal is to (later) unpack/convert the number back into my 3 values.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are the two letters in the string always the same?

Comment: There are 52 * 100 * 26 * 26 = 3515200 combinations, so 1000000 numbers won’t be sufficient. Why didn’t you just do the calculation on your own?

Comment: No, they can be any two letters between a - z (small). But I think this is too much information. How big must my number be (how many digits) so I can store this? Thank you!!

Comment: As @Xufox showed, you'll need 7 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the sallest possible number, but very easy to code,decode: 52992626 if you see what I mean... (wwyyaazz)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily encode all the data you need in a number that is 8 digits wide. (You can do it in fewer, but decoding the following will be easy.)

- First pair of digits: 1 through 26 corresponding to 'a' through 'z'
- Second pair digits: ditto
- Third pair of digits: 0 through 99 for the year
- Fourth pair of digits: 1 through 52 for the week

Of course the order can be changed if it would help (with sorting, for instance). You can build this as follows:

```
public int encode(int week, int year, String letters) {
    int result = letters.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1;
    result = 100 * result + letters.charAt(1) - 'a' + 1;
    result = 100 * result + year;
    result = 100 * result + week;
    return result;
}
```

It can be decoded as follows:

```
public void decode(int encoded) {
    int week = encoded % 100;
    encoded /= 100;
    int year = encoded % 100;
    encoded /= 100;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char) encoded / 100 + 'a' - 1);
    sb.append((char) (encoded % 100) + 'a' - 1);
    String letters = sb.toString();
    // do something with week, year, and letters
}
```

All of this can be done at the bit level as well, which would result in faster execution but would not be readily human-readable.